# HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: URL) returns 0 in iOS 11

Tags: cookies, ios11

I have tried hard to fix this issue for more than two hours but unable to understand what is happening.

I am actually trying to store the cookie returned from Server for AuthLogin URL in my APP.The following code works for iOS version less than iOS11 but in iOS 11 `HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: responseheaderFields, for: URL)` returns 0 element.Please add your inputs to solve this issue.Thanks in Advance.

```
if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    if
                        let responseheaderFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String :String],
                        let URL = response.request?.url {

                        let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
                        cookieStorage.cookieAcceptPolicy =  .always
                        print("policy: \(cookieStorage.cookieAcceptPolicy.rawValue)")

                        // Store session cookie in Keychain
                        let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: responseheaderFields, for: URL)
                        let cookieToStore = cookies.filter(
                        { $0.name == "MY_COOKIE" }).first
                        Application.sessionCookie = cookieToStore
                        print("Cookie ==> \(cookieToStore!)")
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Am not getting any error but I get 0 cookies  for                                    cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: responseheaderFields, for: URL) only for iOS11.I am getting cookie for version < iOS11.Because of this issue unable to save the cookie required for next web services.

Comment: For further details in responseheaderFields I can see the cookie but when I try to extract from  let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: responseheaderFields, for: URL) I get "0 elements" even when the cookie is present in the headerField.Without this cookie I cannot fire the subsequent request and this is a blocker for my App.Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Also come up with this problem. I figured out another workaround

```
func setCookies(dictionary: [String: String]) {
    for (name, value) in dictionary {
        if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
            .domain: ".xxxx.com",
            .path: "/",
            .name: name,
            .value: value
            ]) {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```